How to Route *.example.com to Cloud Run or a VM Using Google Cloud Services
Our app uses subdomains such as store1.example.com and store2.example.com, where each subdomain represents a unique, publicly accessible storefront created by our customers. We want to route all *.example.com traffic to a specific Cloud Run service from Godaddy. How can we configure Cloud Run to accept requests from any subdomain under example.com along with SSL? Alternatively, is there another solution within GCP to handle this use case

Have a look at Mapping custom domains.

If you want to direct all traffic from multiple subdomains (like store1.example.com, store2.example.com, etc.) to a single Cloud Run service, the process is straightforward. Here's how you can do it:
To setup the following architecture, you can follow this doc https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-https-serverless
Set Up a Cloud Load Balancer:
First, create a Cloud Load Balancer in Google Cloud. The load balancer will act as the gateway for all incoming traffic from your subdomains.
Attach Cloud Run as the Backend:
In the load balancer configuration, choose Cloud Run as the backend service. This means that all traffic passing through the load balancer will be forwarded to your Cloud Run service.
Point Your Domains to the Load Balancer:
Next, in your domain provider (like GoDaddy), point all the subdomains (e.g., store1.example.com, store2.example.com) to the same external IP address of your load balancer.
Automatically Handle All Traffic:
Since you have a single Cloud Run service as the backend, all traffic from any subdomain (like store1.example.com, store2.example.com, etc.) will be routed to the same backend service without needing extra configuration.
Please let me know if it's working for you or if you have any other queries
